# how to convert the percentage into decimal in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Write an SQL statement to get all patient details for all patients whose weight is
above the average of the patients of the same gender in the same ward by more
than 20%.

```
SELECT * FROM patient p1
WHERE weight > 1.2*(select avg(weight)
FROM patient p2 WHERE p1.gender = p2.gender AND p1.ward_no = p2.ward_no)
```

why the 20% is converted to 1.2 not 0.2? if we want to convert the percentage to decimal it must give us 20/100=0.2 not 1.2>>>?????

Comment: If person a weighs 20% more than person b, you could say person a's weight  is 120% of person b's weight.

Comment: Erm, this IS basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the 20% on to the average weight and comparing to that. EG: if the average is 5 then 5 + (20% of 5) = 6 or the same as 1.2 x 5.